# source ~/.bashrc for all my shell sessions of my gnu screen at once

Tags: gnu-screen

Is it possible to run `source ~/.bashrc` once but for all my N shell sessions (I'm talking about sessions related to one gnu screen of course) ?

Same question but for things like `export TEST_VAR=whatever` in one shell sessions.

Comment: When you say Windows, do you mean terminal sessions?

Comment: @RamanSailopal The question is tagged `gnu-screen`, so I presume it's related to windows within a `screen` session.

Comment: How do you usually start your `screen` sessions? The sessions would inherit the environment variables from the calling shell.

Comment: @Kusalananda I just run `screen`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have N shell sessions in one GNU screen and you want to execute a given shell command (such as `source ~/.bashrc` or `export TEST_VAR=whatever`) in all shell sessions at once.

This can be done from inside your screen session with:

<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>`:at "#" stuff "export TEST_VAR='whatever'\n"`

This can be done from anywhere with:

```
screen -X at "#" stuff "export TEST_VAR='whatever'\n"
```

(you may want to specify a particular screen session with the `-S` option)